# Deploy two seperate application (Nuxt app & Laravel) in VULTR

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, vultr

I am using VULTR to deploy my nuxt & Laravel application. I have a nuxt application in my_ipaddress:3000 & a Laravel application inside my_ipaddress:5000.

Is it possible to deploy my laravel project inside a folder for example "admin" of my nuxt application, and access the Laravel app like 45.63.82.97:3000/admin ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to configure nginx as a reverse proxy to route /admin requests to laravel

You can use the following tutorial as a reference https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04